# Populating calendar table with codes for dates between tests

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

## My file

[This is my example pbix file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oehp3PFu4cui_ULgJG6-_PPcR-7gc3Ps/view?usp=sharing)

## My data model

I have got **Calendar table** created in DAX. Picture shows only first 3 rows as an example.

```
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
    "Month", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmmm" ),
    "Month Number", MONTH( [Date] )
)
```

[image]

I have got **Maturity table** with sample test results for different Growers / Orchards / ManagementAreas on some dates. Again, shows only a few rows as an example. Both tables are related by Date/SampleDate (1-*).

[image]

I use a **measure AAA** to populate dates when there are some test results with associated Code. To this point it's ok.

```
AAA = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date]) = SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[SampleDate]), SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Code]),"")
```

## Goal

I have a table below, values are AAA measure as above. How to **fill the days when there were no results in a way that it uses the Code from the previous test, until a new test is done**? The ideal results shown in the picture below, in red (codes A, B, C...and possibly X and N/A).

[image]

## Attempts

**1)**
I can't use MAX to select the last date with a Code because it would populate only the very last one everywhere (eg. B to 15/4 - 18/4 for the second row = section B) after 19/4 with a new Code result.

**2)**
I tried to fill the gaps between the test dates with the last Code for each unique combination of Grower, Orchard, and ManagementArea (formula below). Unfortunately, the table shows no values in this case. I can't figure out where I'm making mistakes. This is getting really complex and I'm still a newbie in Power BI and DAX.

```
AAA = 
VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date])
VAR SampleCode =
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Code]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[SampleDate], 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] <= SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
VAR PreviousSample =
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[SampleDate]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] < SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
VAR NextSample =
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[SampleDate]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] > SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        SampleCode <> BLANK(),
        SampleCode,
        IF(
            SelectedDate > PreviousSample && SelectedDate < NextSample,
            CALCULATE(
                SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Code]),
                ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[SampleDate], 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
                'Maturity'[SampleDate] = PreviousSample,
                'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
            ),
            BLANK()
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DAX code in attempt 2 is very close. The logic is:

1. Save the calendar date of cell in table visual.
2. Save the maturity **code** from that date if one exists in the maturity table.
3. Save the most recent prior date from the maturity table (prior to the calendar date), if one exists.
4. Save the next date from the maturity table (after the calendar date), if one exists.
5. If a maturity code from step 2 exists, return that. Otherwise, if the calendar date falls between a prior & next date, return the code from the prior date. Otherwise, return blank (e.g., the calendar date is before the first reading or after the last reading)

However, you're using SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Sample Date]), which will return a blank if more than one prior sample date exists in the maturity table. This situation will be quite common - I imagine you'll have data for lots of dates.

Given that, if you use MAX instead of SELECTEDVALUE, it will return the most recent previous sample date regardless of how many prior sample dates there may be. Likewise with NextSample (which can use MIN or MAX since you're only using it to see if there's a future sample date). You don't want to blank out if there are 2 future sample dates given that this will be the case for a lot of historic dates.

Only use SELECTEDVALUE when you want your measure to return nothing if there's more than one value.

Finally, your SampleCode variable is also looking for a code today or on any prior date. To me, it makes sense to only look for a code today. By doing this, all of the logic for which code to show lives in the final IF statement.

Incorporating these small changes, I get:

```
AAA = 
VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Calendar'[Date])
VAR SampleCode =
    CALCULATE(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Code]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[SampleDate], 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] = SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
VAR PreviousSample =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('Maturity'[SampleDate]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] < SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
VAR NextSample =
    CALCULATE(
        MIN('Maturity'[SampleDate]),
        ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
        'Maturity'[SampleDate] > SelectedDate,
        'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
    )
RETURN
    IF(
        SampleCode <> BLANK(),
        SampleCode,
        IF(
            SelectedDate > PreviousSample && SelectedDate < NextSample,
            CALCULATE(
                SELECTEDVALUE('Maturity'[Code]),
                ALLEXCEPT('Maturity', 'Maturity'[SampleDate], 'Maturity'[Grower], 'Maturity'[Orchard], 'Maturity'[ManagementArea]),
                'Maturity'[SampleDate] = PreviousSample,
                'Maturity'[Code] <> BLANK()
            ),
            BLANK()
        )
    )
```

Optional note: Given that you have a calendar table, you could do ALL('Calendar'[Date]) instead of ALLEXCEPT and a list of every column you want to keep the filters on. This does change the logic slightly though, so I haven't done so. Alternatively, if you had an ID field to represent the grower/orchard/area, you could ALLEXCEPT just that field.

I hope this helps.